# Actualizar unicamente tabla .ASP

Tags: ajax, asp.net, datatable

Tengo un proyecto que al cargar mi primera vista me muestra una tabla con usuarios en ella muestra información como nombre, apellido, rfc, etc., únicamente muestra la información traída desde mi controlador y tiene unos cuantos botones que de acuerdo con el status del usuario cambia el color. El problema que tengo es que los usuarios son registrados desde otra aplicación (escritorio) y me gustaría que la tabla actualizara cada cierto tiempo sin necesidad de recargar la página entera. La información la envió desde mi controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
        public ActionResult turnos()
    {
        if (!Session["message"].Equals("Admin"))
        {
            datalist = new DataSet();
            datalist = GeneralFnt.FillTable("select id, Name, RFC, FirstLastname, SecondLastname, status, Date, kid from Usuarios where status between 0 and 7 order by idInterview  desc");
            var Model = datalist.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(user => new Usuario()
            {
                id= user.Field<int>("id"),
                Name = user.Field<String>("Name"),
                FirstLastname = user.Field<String>("FirstLastname"),
                SecondLastname = user.Field<String>("SecondLastname"),
                RFC = user.Field<String>("RFC"),
                status = user.Field<int>("status"),
                Kid= user.Field<String>("Kid"),
                Date = user.Field<DateTime>("Date")
            });
            var list = Model.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "login");
        }
    }
```

posteriormente creo mi tabla en mi vista y con foreach recorro la lista que fue enviada y la coloco en la tabla de la siguiente manera

```
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 12px;" overflow-y:hidden">
            <button onclick="fresh();"></button>
            <table style="width:100%" id="ControlRH" border="0" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:auto">id</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Nombre</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Apellido Paterno</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Apellido Materno</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">RFC</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Hora de llegada</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Postulado para:</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Primera Entrevista RH</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Servicio Medico</th>
                        <th style="width:auto">Consultar</th>

                </thead>
                <tbody id="body">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td id="idhidden">@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.idInterview)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Name)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.FirstLastname)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.SecondLastname)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.RFC)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Date)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.kindInterview)</td>

                            @if (item.status == 1)
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Continuar", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", })</td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Iniciar", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Turnos", "Showturns", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                </td>
                            }
                            @if (item.status == 0)
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Iniciar", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn  btn-default" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Iniciar", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Turnos", "Showturns", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                </td>
                            }
                            @if (item.status == 2)
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Terminado", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Iniciar", "show", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @id = "idmodal", @class = "btn btn-default", @data_toggle = "modal", @data_target = "#modalSubscriptionForm", @data_parameter = item.idInterview })</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Turnos", "Showturns", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                </td>
                            }
                            @if (item.status == 3)
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Iniciar", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Continuar", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Turnos", "Showturns", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                </td>
                            }
                            @if (item.status == 6)
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Completado", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Completado", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Showturns", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                                </td>
                            }

                            @if (item.status == 7)
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Completado", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Completado", "InterView", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Showturns", new { id = item.idInterview }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>

                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

hasta aqui funciona todo perfectamente, la cuestion es que como mencionaba, necesito actualizar la tabla, sé que una opcion es usar ajax y poner los nuevos  a la tabla actualmente lo consigo del siguiente manera

```
function fresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/RH/updateTable',
        success: function (result) {
           for (var i in result) {
               $('#tableid').append('<tr><td>' + result[i].id+ '</td><td>' + result[i].Name + '</td><td>' + result[i].FirstLastname + '</td><td>' + result[i].SecondLastname + '</td><td>' + result[i].RFC + '</td><td>' + result[i].Date +'</td><td>' + result[i].Kind+ '</td></tr>');
            }

        }
    });
}
```

lo que hice fue crear otro controlador que me traiga la misma informacion que la funcion que se ejecuta al cargar por primera vez la pagina (No sé si funciona si vuelvo a llamar a la misma funcion). Cabe aclarar que la función fresh() la uso en un botón unicamente como prueba.
Otra cuestión es como puedo agregar de nuevo los botones, ya que como se pueden dar cuenta uso sintaxis Razer (espero así se llame, por que soy muy novato en .ASP) además que de hacer el append no borra nada de la tabla original solo se agregan de nuevos los mismos valores, que eso no es tanto problema, creo...

Bueno espero puedan ayudarme ya que he dejado este tema muy al ultimo y ya casi es tiempo de entregar.
MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Ajax

Controlador

```
        [HttpPost]
    public string CargarTabla(UserEntity UserEntity) {

        return Tabla //El Json o XML
    }
```

Vista

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CargarTabla")",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {dato1: "hola"},

        success: function (XmlDoc) {
            $("#tabla tbody tr").remove()
            //Cargar la nueva info
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Y para que cargue cada x tiempo puedes usar un timer ([introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp))

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Comment: Buen día, la informacion no es el problema. El problema es que utilizo botones y eso es donde no se me ocurre como poder ponerlos sin que se cambie la funcionalidad